# Sqlite login Runtime error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to Android and facing some problem in sqlite db while accessing db. I have created a table with default values, I'm trying to login with that default values so it's giving runtime error.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.defaultdb;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn;
EditText ename, epass;
private Logindatabase logindb;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
Context context = this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        logindb = new Logindatabase(this);
        logindb = logindb.open();

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = logindb.getWritableDatabase();
        logindb = new Logindatabase(this);
        logindb.insertContact("harsh@me", "141");
        logindb.insertContact("leena@me", "120");
        logindb.insertContact("rahul@me", "921");

        Cursor allContacts = logindb.getAllContacts();

        //createDatabase();
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ename=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        epass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String userName = ename.getText().toString();
                String password = epass.getText().toString();

                String storedPassword = logindb.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

        if (epass.equals(storedPassword)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Next.class);
            startActivity(main);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "User Name or Password does not match",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});


}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        logindb.close();
    }


}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

DBHelper.java

```
package com.example.defaultdb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(Logindatabase.CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) {
        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " + _oldVersion + " to "
                + _newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");

        onCreate(_db);
    }

}
```

Logindatabase.java

```
package com.example.defaultdb;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

public class Logindatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static interface CONTACT extends BaseColumns{
        static final String DATABASE_TABLE= "login";
        static final String KEY_EMAIL="email";
        static final String KEY_PASS="pass";

    }

    static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS";
    static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
    static final String TAG="DBAdapter";
    static final String DATABASE_NAME= "MyDB";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION=3;

    static final String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT= CREATE_TABLE + CONTACT.DATABASE_TABLE +" ("+ CONTACT._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + 
                                            CONTACT.KEY_EMAIL + "TEXT," + CONTACT.KEY_PASS + "TEXT DEFAULT 'TTEESSTT');";
    // static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" IF EXITS";


    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    public Logindatabase(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //this.context=context;
    //  DBHelper=new DatabaseHelper(context);
        //Message.message(context,"constructor called");
    }

    //open the database
    public Logindatabase open() throws SQLException{
        db =dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         return this;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        try{
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            //e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try{


        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version" + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ",which will destroy all odl data");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + CONTACT.DATABASE_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

//closes the database
public void close()
{
    //DBHelper.close();
    close();
}
public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance() {
    return db;
}


public Cursor getAllContacts(){
    return getReadableDatabase().query(CONTACT.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null,null);

}

//insert values
public void insertContact(String email, String pass){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CONTACT.KEY_EMAIL, email);
    if(pass!=null) {
        values.put(CONTACT.KEY_PASS, pass);
    }
     getWritableDatabase().insert(CONTACT.DATABASE_TABLE,null,values);
    //return logindb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName) {

    Cursor cursor = db.query("LOGIN", null, " KEY_EMAIL=?",
            new String[] { userName }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("KEY_PASS"));
    cursor.close();
    return password
}


}
```

Comment: please show the error stacktrace

Comment: first always check your db  or table is created or not..ok.keep in mind dear for next time so you get exact problem

Comment: First remove the try-catch blocks that ignore exceptions. Then uninstall your app. Then you'll get logcat with specific stacktrace that tells what is wrong.

Comment: i don't know how to check table or db is created or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You have made no space between `CREATE_TABLE` and `CONTACT.DATABASE_TABLE`, the string would be:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTSlogin
```

and this will defenitely lead into an error. It must be for example:

```
CREATE_TABLE + " " +CONTACT.DATABASE_TABLE
```

to build a proper String, add a space between these two, then it will be:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login
```

But without seeing a stacktrace, we can´t give you a concrete answer

Comment: please, if someone edits my answer, look at the meaning first. I pointed out the wrong CREATE_TABLE string and shows only how it will be made by the questioner. There is no space between....